# rdmd is not running unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, d

I have a class file with a unit test block in it like so

```
class SomeClass {
  // class stuff...
  unittest {
    // unit test stuff...
  }
}
```

and when I run `rdmd --main -unittest someclass.d` nothing happens. Just for good measure I made sure to have some failing assertions in the unit test block but again nothing happens. What am I missing?

I'm running all of this on Ubuntu with rdmd build 20120401.

Here's the output of `rdmd` with `--chatty`:

```
rdmd -unittest --main --chatty linkedlist.d
'dmd' '-unittest' '-v' '-o-' 'linkedlist.d' '-I.'
'/tmp/.rdmd-1000/home/david/D_Finger_Exercises/linkedlist.d.6374859E23D5272488D4E396AEDC7BE1'
```

Here's the link to the files I've been using : https://github.com/davidk01/D-Finger-Exercises/

Comment: it's hard to help you without more info... you're code should work, at least is similar to the example: http://dlang.org/unittest.html

Comment: you need to use --main flag because your code don't have a main method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your bug. Here's my test code:

```
class SomeClass {
  // class stuff...
  unittest {
    import std.stdio;
    writeln("unittested");
  }
}
```

With the code above saved in a file called test.d, I ran:

rdmd -unittest --main test.d

and got "unittested" printed to stdout.

You may want to add --chatty to flags so you see exactly how dmd is invoked.

Comment: I ran your template with --chatty and nothing happened. Here's the output of rdmd with --chatty `VirtualBox:~/D_Finger_Exercises$ rdmd -unittest --main --chatty linkedlist.d
'dmd' '-unittest' '-v' '-o-' 'linkedlist.d' '-I.'
'/tmp/.rdmd-1000/home/david/D_Finger_Exercises/linkedlist.d.6374859E23D5272488D4E396AEDC7BE1'`

Comment: Your paste shows both your prompt, what you typed, and presumably the output. Please (a) clarify what's what, (b) check your installation, (c) remove /tmp/.rdmd/, (d) post linkedlist.d. I'd be glad to elp but essentially you need a complete and reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry. a) The output is what follows after `linkedlist.d`. b) What exactly should I check about my installation? Everything else seems to work ok. As a workaround I've been putting the unit tests into its own file with a main method and it seems to be working fine. c) I removed `/tmp/rdmd` but it didn't do anything. d) I've added the link to `linkedlist.d` to my question.

Comment: The file linkedlist.d (https://github.com/davidk01/D-Finger-Exercises/blob/master/linkedlist.d) imports nothing and has no unittests. rdmd correctly compiles it alone without any other files in the directory. Therefore there are no unittests to run in the first place.

Comment: That's true but I removed all unit tests and put them into their own files with a main method so that I could run them. I know that rdmd compiles it just fine and it compiles it just fine with unit tests as well but the unit tests don't run, i.e. there is no visible output even if the unit test block has a call to `writefln`.

Comment: I think the question to ask here is, do you have a brief, complete, and reproducible example showing that rdmd does not run the unittests?

Comment: Yes. With my setup unit tests consistently don't run with `rdmd -unittest --main`. I have added a unit test block back to `linkedlist.d` and whenever I run `rdmd -unittest --main linkedlist.d` there is no output even though the unit test block contains a call to `writefln`. It is consistently reproducible with my setup. I haven't tried any of this yet on a Windows box.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running it with the -debug flag?

Answer (score 2):

Your `LinkedList` class is templated. The `unittest` block is run for every instantiation of that template; i.e. zero times.

Answer (score 1):

Your file doesn't have a `main` function, so nothing will run. Add a `main` function and your unit tests will be invoked as expected.

Comment: doesn't the --main option create a default entry point just for testing purposes?

Comment: `rdmd` with `--main` is supposed to insert an empty main function. At least that's what the documentation for `rdmd` says. That's why I'm wondering what exactly I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try reordering the arguments. For whatever reason, for me at least, rdmd only acknowledges the dmd arguments (`-unittest` `-I` etc) if they precede the rdmd arguments (`--main`). I believe there is a very brief mention of this in the docs, but I'm not sure.

Comment: No go. I tried it both ways and unit tests in both cases do not run.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Worth a shot. ;) Hope you get it figured out.

Comment: I think this was a bug that was fixed a long time ago.